# Вывести строки таблицы БД firebird через PHP

Tags: php, база-данных, firebird, interbase

Возникла проблема, не могу вывести строки из базы данных.
Удачно приконнектился, правильно выводит число строк в таблице, но почему то выводит пустоту.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Структура таблицы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Записи:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<?php
function ibase_num_rows($query) {
$i = 0; while (ibase_fetch_row($query)) {    $i++;  } return $i;}

 ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

            $database = 'localhost:D:\\CAR.GDB';
            $user     = 'SYSDBA';
            $password = 'masterkey';
            $db = ibase_connect($database, $user, $password);
            if ($db=true) echo "connect";
            else echo "no connect";

$query ="SELECT * FROM KLYENT";

$result = ibase_query($query) or die("Ошибка " . ibase_errcode($link)); 
if($result)
{
    $rows = ibase_num_rows($result); // количество полученных строк

   echo "<table><tr><th> Клиент Id</th><th>Фамилия</th><th>Имя</th><th>Отчество</th><th>Адрес</th> <th>Телефон</th></tr>";
    for ($i = 0 ; $i < $rows ; ++$i)
    {
       $row = ibase_fetch_row($result);

        echo "<tr>";
            for ($j = 0 ; $j < 6 ; ++$j) 
            {
            echo "<td>";
            //echo $j;
            echo $row[$j];}
            echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";

}

;
// Выводим переданные данные на экран 

print "<b>Данные извлечены.</b><br>"; 
            ?>
```

Comment: что показывает var_dump($row)

Comment: @AntonKucenko false false, что странно

Answer (score 0):

У вас опечатка. Строка `if ($db=true)` всегда вернет true, т.к. это присваивание, а не сравнение.

Comment: Да, это я не увидел, но это ни на что не влияет в данном случае. Проблему решил сам. Ошибка была в моей функции, которая считает строки. Ибо когда идет обход построчно, предыдущая строка удаляется, итого имеем пустой $result.